# Add attribute in sub-menu WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Kindly check the following HTML code for displaying my menu section.

```
 <div class="csidemenu collapse" id="collapseExample">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenuwork" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="submenuwork">WORK</a>
                    <ul class="collapse" id="submenuwork">
                        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="residential.php">Residential</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">F & B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leisure</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Retail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Workspaces</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.php">STUDIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AWARDS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PRESS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
```

How can I make this dynamic by using nav menu function?

Comment: The proper way to do that is to write your own [Walker Nav Menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) object. See example [here](https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/). Be prepared, is quite complex to understand process.

Comment: I tried. This is too complex to understand.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no simpler way to do what you want. There's another case with `ob_start(); ... ob_get_clean()` + Regular Expression Replace, but this is too error prone solution and not recommended at all.